# preserving text formatting while reading and displaying text

Tags: php, text

i am trying to display the contents of a file in a browser using php and was wondering how to preserve the text formatting of the file.

for example if the file was formatted as follows:

```
<?php
$fh = fopen("somefile.php", 'r') or die ("could not open file");
?>
```

it currently displays inline like this:

```
<?php $fh = open("some file.php", 'r') or die (could not open file") ?>
```

is there any way to preserve the formatting s

Answer (score 0):

Put the output in a `<pre>` block to indicate that they're preformatted.

```
<pre>
<?php
readfile($filename);
?>
</pre>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to escape all special symbols like $?<>[]'"`/etc and restore them before displaying (urldecode/urlencode or html_entity_decode/htmlentities).
May be the better way for you to store such content in file in binary format.

Comment: Not `urlencode`, that's for encoding URL parameters, not HTML.